# Return current page type

Tags: custom-post-types, pages

Is there a function that simply returns the current "page type" instead of using is_page(), is_preview(), is_single(), is_archive(), etc?

For example: I can find the current "post type" but I can't find it's corresponding "page type".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need your own helper function which will return you what you need. It could be like this one:

```
function wpse8170_loop() {
    global $wp_query;
    $loop = 'notfound';

    if ( $wp_query->is_page ) {
        $loop = is_front_page() ? 'front' : 'page';
    } elseif ( $wp_query->is_home ) {
        $loop = 'home';
    } elseif ( $wp_query->is_single ) {
        $loop = ( $wp_query->is_attachment ) ? 'attachment' : 'single';
    } elseif ( $wp_query->is_category ) {
        $loop = 'category';
    } elseif ( $wp_query->is_tag ) {
        $loop = 'tag';
    } elseif ( $wp_query->is_tax ) {
        $loop = 'tax';
    } elseif ( $wp_query->is_archive ) {
        if ( $wp_query->is_day ) {
            $loop = 'day';
        } elseif ( $wp_query->is_month ) {
            $loop = 'month';
        } elseif ( $wp_query->is_year ) {
            $loop = 'year';
        } elseif ( $wp_query->is_author ) {
            $loop = 'author';
        } else {
            $loop = 'archive';
        }
    } elseif ( $wp_query->is_search ) {
        $loop = 'search';
    } elseif ( $wp_query->is_404 ) {
        $loop = 'notfound';
    }

    return $loop;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping WP had something built-in to handle this. Unfortunately not! Thanks for the function!

Comment: Somehow it's 2022 and there is still no native WP function for this. Brilliant answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
var_dump(get_query_var('post_type'));
```

but even than that page can be a single or archive or anything else...

What you tring to achive? Perhaps in that case will be more understand what you need.

update.
take a look to sample theme function that you can use to achive this task. function called twentyeleven_body_classes from [Twentyeleven](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/twentyeleven) theme. it returns clases that can be used for body_classes filter

```
function twentyeleven_body_classes( $classes ) {

    if ( function_exists( 'is_multi_author' ) && ! is_multi_author() )
        $classes[] = 'single-author';

    if ( is_singular() && ! is_home() && ! is_page_template( 'showcase.php' ) && ! is_page_template( 'sidebar-page.php' ) )
        $classes[] = 'singular';

    return $classes;
}
```

nothing holding you from not adding to it additional classes. is_archive() or something else... in this case you got a page types you want.

Comment: What I want to know is if the page is single, archive, attachment, etc. I don't care about the post type.

Comment: In this take as example on of the body_classes functions. one of tham given in update code.

Answer (score 0):

If you place this template tag within the Body tag `<?php body_class(); ?>` It will output it in your code i.e. `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>` That will give you the templates referenced for the given page.

Alternatively you could echo the path to the page template being called i.e. page.php or single-posttype.php by using this: `<?php echo get_page_template() ?>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little too late but a better and small solution using array filter would be:

```
function getPage( $arrayIn ) {
    $prefix = 'is_';

    $array = array_filter( array_filter( (array) $arrayIn, function ( $key ) use ( $prefix ) {
        return ( strpos( $key, $prefix ) === 0 );
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY ) );

    unset( $array['is_singular'] );

    return preg_replace( '/^' . preg_quote( $prefix, '/' ) . '/', '', key( $array ) );
}
```